# What's the rule governing the use of an indefinite article with a noun?

Tags: definite-article, as, understanding

[Source](http://edumantra.net/sleepy-little-town/)

> Gazing at them for hours on end, sitting on the sandy river bank, was a great help to me. I could wash away my anguish and disgust over life. The anguish and disgust were caused by my guardians. They insisted on my taking to **as irrational *an* occupation as learning** how to read and write.

I have been unable to understand the structure and meaning of the bold part.

Also, the article usage in **irrational *an* occupation** seems a bit odd to me and I think it should be like ***an* irrational occupation**.

Comment: I wonder if you find it more readable if you change the word order: ***They insisted on my taking to an occupation as irrational as learning how to read and write.*** That's pretty much what the original means as well, it's just that the word order is tweaked for effect.

Answer (score 4):

This use of *an* is a mannerism, a stylistic tool, a flourish of the language, used here to strengthen the satirical meaning of the simile - after all, it's not to be taken literally (learning being a very rational occupation).

Normally, this would be **an occupation as irrational as learning**. The article in the original is an archaic form that mostly fell out of use, and here it's used in a facetious manner, to emphasize the mocking tone of the expression.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how "as irrational occupation as learning" would work - *occupation* is a countable noun, so it needs an article.  Can you explain?

Comment: @stangdon Agreed, that first wording as it would "normally" be is not heard and makes little sense. The second one is a very helpful rephrasing for learners.

Comment: I deleted the dubious part. Agreed, that thinking where it would fit smoothly I came up blank.